# Rails 7. Devise error validation: Email can't be blank Password can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I get an error of validation when try to register a new user.
 `Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank`
I create custom devise controllers. I have the next code in registrations' controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  include ApplicationHelper
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :check_existing_user, only: [:new]

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
  end

  def check_existing_user
    @user = User.last
    
    if @user
      redirect_to sign_in_path, danger: 'User alredy exists. Please sign in.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

And I left permited parameters for devise in applocation controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }

  devise_scope :user do  
    get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get 'sign_up', to: 'users/registrations#new'
    get 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    resources :users, only: [:show]
  end
```

and User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

Console log doesn't return some errors. I fill form right. Why do I get it?

Comment: Can you check the value of `@params` in your controller?

Comment: @Jax. How can I do i?

Comment: if `def crate` stick a `debugger` or `binding.pry` the when the server stops just key in `@params`

Comment: @Jax debugger after line ' build_resource(configure_sign_up_params)' which I added in create-method returns 'resource #<User id: nil, email: "", username: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>'. Do you know where does devise write this variable?

Comment: @Jax I got another error 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty' from form of new view and had to add  resource hepler like said here https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/2451. Prehaps it was mistake.

Comment: The error was in my method check_existing_user. I changed @user to resource_user and it works as I expect.